# c# Async socket based gaming programme

Tags: c#-4.0

I have developed c# async socket based game. Server is continuously sending commands to client, and according those commands client works. It works fine but when internet connection slows down or some miss behavior commands are miss-placed then client behaves abrupt behavior.
In simple server sending commands asynchronously but at the receiver of client need to have some synchronous mechanism to catch all those commands.

I want some experts advise, Please help me.. I am really frustrated about this issue it comes sometime in week or month or never come.

Waiting for reply.....

Comment: you can as it here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you buffer incoming commands? Do you use TCP or UDP?

Comment: I am using TCP and buffer size 8192. After receiving command I add in queue and processing one by one.